# JEvent is it possible to have each user have its own calendar?

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to have events and calendar only to each user to see and modify in their account?

And have a moderator or admin setup to see all their events in a query or list?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible but depending on the number of users it would be a serious pain to administer. You would have to set up a new calendar for each user since JEvents does not have a way to create new calendars through the front end. You would also need to modify the JEvent code so that only the logged in user's calendar shows up to keep it private. You'd probably be better off finding a component that is meant to do this unless you are capable of coding it yourself.

Comment: would you know another calender that will let me do what i want. its ok if its commercial. thanks for your reply

Comment: JEvents may have a plugin that will work for you. One of the club plugins is called Personal Private Events. I'm not sure if an admin would be able to see anything on the front end but I would guess that you could see all of the events through the backend. http://www.jevents.net/en/home-topmenu-3/news-topmenu-5/1-general-news/42-extra-features-available-to-club-members